# Can I ask a new question to ask whether an answer I gave is correct, targeting a knowledgeable audience via the language-lawyer tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, duplicate-questions

I've recently gave [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73923827/5825294) to [a question about value cateogries in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73923530/5825294), and the author accepted it.

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure about the correctness (or at least *thoroughness*) of my answer, so I'd like to ask a question along the lines of "Is this answer of mine really correct?". I think that would make it almost a duplicate by definition, the only things making it different being

- that I would attach the [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag to make it different, because I don't look for an answer from somebody far more experienced than me,
- and that I would stress the point of distinguishing the `xvalue` vs `prvalue` args *inside the callee* rather than at the call site (this is clearly visible in the linked question, but not stated).

Would such a question be rightfully closed as a duplicate of the linked one?

Or, using other words, is [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) sufficient to make a new question not be duplicate of an existing one without that tag (assuming the latter has no answer conforming to that tag)?

Comment: Just adding [language-lawyer] wouldn't necessarily count as a different question - you would also have to phrase the question in a way that would require an answer to quote the standard. It would be helpful if you included the question you would like to ask in this meta post, so it's a little clearer what it would look like.

Comment: @cigien, the second bullet point refers to the attempt of narrowing the scope of the question to allow for a language-lawyer answer.

Comment: So you take a jab at a comment because it's a XY problem, but *answer* said XY problem? What makes you think *your* answer is useful to a wide audience then? (As your now deleted comment wanted to know from whomever downvoted)

Comment: It does seem like this appeal to language lawyering is all due to a single downvote rustling your feathers.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica. No. I'd have asked this question much earlier.

Comment: @Enlico Ah, I see, the second bullet makes it clearer. Yeah, go for it, if you can ask a more constrained language-lawyer question based on this question. You can link to it, and mention how it's related.

Answer (score 13):

Rather than ask "Is my answer correct?", ask a *specific* question about the *thing that you need to verify* in order to be sure of the correctness of your answer. The new question should be able to stand on its own. If all you can think of asking is "does my answer correctly answer this question?", then that does not meaningfully differ from "what is the correct answer to this question?", which is equivalent to the question itself.

If others have specific quibbles with your answer, that's what the comments are for. If they think the answer is wrong, or otherwise bad, that's what downvotes are for.

If you lack confidence in the key point of an answer, consider not answering. However, if you lack confidence in technical details, the usual mechanisms should be good enough.

You can also consider adding [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) to the *original* question, if the question is asking how some language feature is *supposed* to work. However, if the original question is asking *how* to do something, [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) is not appropriate, even if the most reasonable answer is along the lines of "No, it's not possible to do this, because the standard says so in <link>."

Comment: Probably adding that tag is the best option :/ Hopefully somebody will post a more autoritative answer.

Comment: @Enlico No, adding that tag is definitely not a good option. A [language-lawyer] question has much stricter requirements for an answer, i.e. an *answer* must answer the question in terms of what the standard says. Adding that tag to a "how-to" question because you feel your answer needs a language-lawyer clarification isn't a good idea, and in fact that tag changes the intent of the question - the question is asking how to solve a problem, not what the language says about it. An answer can still quote the standard if it wants to, of course.

Comment: @Enlico Also, I don't see what's wrong with the `xvalue` and `prvalue` tags. The question explicitly mentions those value categories, and the question is relevant for someone filtering by those tags. I've rolled back your edit that changed those 3 tags.

Comment: @cigien Please edit my answer to clarify how that works, because I apparently don't know it well enough myself.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ok, I've edited the last tag related paragraph. Of course, this is just my opinion on the matter, so feel free to edit/rollback if you disagree in any way.